# Maven build fails in Jenkins

Tags: java, maven, jenkins

I have a Maven project following is the directory structure:

```
maven_example/src
maven_example/target
```

In `/src/main/java/maven_example/` I have three `.java` files:

```
Adder.java  MainClass.java  Subtractor.java
```

In `/src/test/java/maven_example/` I have three files:

```
AllTests.java  TestAdder.java  TestSubtractor.java
```

And below is my `pom.xml`:

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
  <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
  <groupId>com.infovision.maven_example</groupId>
  <artifactId>maven_example</artifactId>
  <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
  <build>
  <plugins>
    <plugin>
        <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>2.3.2</version>
        <configuration>
            <source>1.8</source>
            <target>1.8</target>
        </configuration>
    </plugin>
    <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-jar-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>2.4</version>
            <configuration>
                <archive>
                    <manifest>
                        <mainClass>src.main.java.maven_example.MainClass</mainClass>
                    </manifest>
                </archive>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>
   </plugins>
  </build>
<!-- http://mvnrepository.com/artifact/junit/junit -->
  <dependencies>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>junit</groupId>
      <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
      <version>4.11</version>
    </dependency>
  </dependencies>
</project>
```

So, when I run `mvn clean verify` from command line it succeeds.

But in Jenkins build fails with following error message:

```
[maven_example] $ /usr/lib/jvm/java-8-oracle/bin/java /usr/share/maven -cp /var/lib/jenkins/plugins/maven-plugin/WEB-INF/lib/maven3-agent-1.5.jar:/usr/share/maven/boot/plexus-classworlds-2.x.jar org.jvnet.hudson.maven3.agent.Maven3Main /usr/share/maven /var/cache/jenkins/war/WEB-INF/lib/remoting-2.59.jar /var/lib/jenkins/plugins/maven-plugin/WEB-INF/lib/maven3-interceptor-1.5.jar /var/lib/jenkins/plugins/maven-plugin/WEB-INF/lib/maven3-interceptor-commons-1.5.jar 41467
Error: Could not find or load main class .usr.share.maven
ERROR: Failed to launch Maven. Exit code = 1
Finished: FAILURE
```

Following is my setup of Jenkins:

Root POM: `/home/ishan/sf_shared/my_repo/maven/maven_example/pom.xml`

Goals and options: `clean verify`

What could be possibly wrong here?

Comment: This : `/usr/lib/jvm/java-8-oracle/bin/java /usr/share/maven` , attempts to execute a class called `usr.share.maven`. I guess you wanted `/usr/share/maven` in the `-cp` part.

Comment: Your mainClass entry is wrong it should be `maven_example.MainClass` apart from that I'm not sure if an underscore is a llowed in a package name in Java...

Comment: @khmarbaise: Underscores are allowed: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/package/namingpkgs.html

Comment: Ah Thanks haven't found that. I never used them in package names.

Comment: @Berger That command is from Jenkins itself, I am not doing anything there. What I can do to change that in Jenkins??

Comment: @khmarbaise I changed the main class entry, the error still persist. With same message. Build still fails.

Comment: Put your Jenkins Job configuration here.

Comment: 1. `maven-compiler-plugin:2.3.2` is almost 6 years old. I'd use the latest v3.5.1[(1)](http://search.maven.org/#search%7Cgav%7C1%7Cg%3A%22org.apache.maven.plugins%22%20AND%20a%3A%22maven-compiler-plugin%22). 2. `maven-jar-plugin:2.4` is more than 4 years old. I'd use the latest v3.0.2 [(2)](http://search.maven.org/#search%7Cgav%7C1%7Cg%3A%22org.apache.maven.plugins%22%20AND%20a%3A%22maven-jar-plugin%22) 3. Have you checked Jenkins' Maven configuration in _Manage Jenkins_ → _Configure System_ → _Maven_?